# Zip up a folder, but only include folders with numerical names?

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, compression

I have a very messy folder which contains thousands of files and directories. I would like to create a Zip file which only contains some of the folders (and files within those folders) - specifically those folders which have number-only names (104, 2342, etc...).

I can't figure out how to do this though - any suggestions?

I'm on Linux - CentOS to be exact :)

Comment: What command line? You don't mention an OS, is it Windows, Linux, Mac, OS/2, GEM, CP/M, AIS, BeOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work for you:

```
 zip -ry archive.zip [0-9]*
```

Run on a directory containing this:

```
001  002  100  200  aaa  bbb
```

it creates a zip archive of only the numbered directories:

```
$ unzip -l archive.zip 
Archive:  archive.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
        0  2010-10-19 22:27   001/
        0  2010-10-19 22:27   002/
        0  2010-10-19 22:41   100/
        0  2010-10-19 22:41   100/10000/
        0  2010-10-19 22:41   100/10000/a.txt
        0  2010-10-19 22:41   100/10000/10000.txt
        0  2010-10-19 22:27   200/
---------                     -------
        0                     7 files
```

That is only numbered files/dirs at the top level get put in the zip archive.

**UPDATE**
To exclude files from the top level:

find . -maxdepth  1 -type f > excluded.files

review 'excluded.files' carefully. Then:

zip -ry test.zip [0-9]* -x@excluded.files

Comment: almost there; Running that command just zipped every numbered file in the directory + the correct folders, not just the folders - good enough for me though, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use `find` with `-regex` or the like to figure out which folder names are numeric, then use `zip -@` to read the filtered list of filenames piped from `find`.